# Is there a way I could use @MethodSource and @EnumSource in the same @ParameterizedTest

Tags: java, kotlin

Hey I'm trying to use both @MethodSource and @EnumSource in the same @ParameterizedTest
i tried doing the following

```
@ParameterizedTest
@MethodSource("methodTest")
@EnumSource(value = CountryDetails::class, mode = EnumSource.Mode.INCLUDE, names = ["A", "B", "C", "D"])
fun `test name`(
        country: CountryDetails,
        amount: BigDecimal,
        rich: Boolean,
        hight: Int,
    ) {
// here goes my test 
}

@JvmStatic
fun methodTest(): Stream<Arguments> = Stream.of(
   Arguments.of(BigDecimal(800), false, 50),
   Arguments.of(BigDecimal(900), true, 50),
)
```

However I'm getting this error

> Error converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to
> convert object of type java.math.BigDecimal to type
> com.test.country.CountryDetails
> org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ParameterResolutionException: Error
> converting parameter at index 0: No implicit conversion to convert
> object of type java.math.BigDecimal

Comment: I don't think this is possible, because `EnumSource` works only for a single-parameter test function, as far as I know. But why complicate things? Since you're already using a MethodSource, just use that, and add your enums to the Arguments that your method returns.

Answer (score 1):

This will not work, as the method source function provides 3 parameters and must be used by a function with 3 parameters, and the enum source provides 1 parameter and should be used by a function that takes 1 parameter.

The two annotations are completely independent of each other.

If you want some sort of cartesian product of the enums and the parameters you'll have to do it in a loop in the method source:

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.TestInstance
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.Arguments
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource
import java.math.BigDecimal
import java.util.stream.Stream

enum class CountryDetails {
    A, B, C, D
}

data class MethodArgs(val country: CountryDetails, val amount: BigDecimal, val rich: Boolean, val height: Int)

@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
class Test {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("methodTest")
    fun `test name`(
        methodArgs: MethodArgs
    ) {
// here goes my test
    }

        private fun methodTest(): Stream<MethodArgs> =
    listOf(CountryDetails.A, CountryDetails.B, CountryDetails.C, CountryDetails.D).map {
        listOf(MethodArgs(it, BigDecimal(800), false, 50), MethodArgs(it, BigDecimal(900), true, 50))
    }.flatten().stream()
}
```

A couple of points on the code - the test instance annotation means you don't have to write static methods.

Use of a data class makes things a lot easier when dealing with lots of parameters.

Comment: Nice. By the way, the method source doesn't _have_ to return a Stream. It can be any Iterable, so you can also return a List which allows you to remove the call to `.stream()`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about not needing Stream. That, combined with data classes, makes things a lot easier than dealing with Arguments..

I always refer to this excellent page when doing Kotlin tests:|

https://phauer.com/2018/best-practices-unit-testing-kotlin/#avoid-static-and-reuse-the-test-class-instance

Comment: I have often referred to that page too. It's very good, but I wish it was updated since it was written in 2018. It recommends using Kotest for assertions, but since 2018 other libraries have come of age, such as assertK and even assertJ (which I loved when I worked in Java) now has Kotlin extensions.

Answer (score 0):

The provided answers should give you enough info, just so you know, You don't need a data class either if you don't want...

If your test is simple you can provide more values using Pairs or Triples in Kotlin as well so.

Imagine you want to test a phone number validator and need to supply country code, phone number, and the expected result:

```
Stream.of(
            //Country Code, Phone number, expected value
            Arguments.of(Pair("", ""), ""),
            Arguments.of(Pair("", "12345"), "12345"),
            Arguments.of(Pair("+31", "12345"), "+3112345")
```

You get the idea.

Your test would look like:

```
    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("methodTest")
    fun testXXX(input: Pair<String, String>, expected: String) {
        val formatted = subject.format(input.first, input.second)
        assertEquals(expected, formatted)
    }
```

Keep it in mind as it may make your test simpler.